# How do I eliminate a second seq scan over a table when deriving a new table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, ctas, postgresql-performance

Let's say I have some sample data, 100 million rows.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT id, md5(id::text), trunc(random()*1e6)
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS t(id);
```

This will generate a table like this..

```
 id |               md5                | trunc  
----+----------------------------------+--------
  1 | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b | 159632
  2 | c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c | 182952
  3 | eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3 | 438287
  4 | a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c |  78240
  5 | e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5 |  20293
  6 | 1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc | 909742
  7 | 8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543 | 926496
  8 | c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d | 463718
  9 | 45c48cce2e2d7fbdea1afc51c7c6ad26 |  65842
 10 | d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820 |  81791
```

How can I then generate a table with one scan that resembles this..

```
SELECT id, md5::text AS x
FROM foo
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, trunc::text
  FROM foo;

 id |                x                 
----+----------------------------------
  1 | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
  1 | 961453
  2 | c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
  2 | 842364
  3 | eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3
  3 | 784693
  4 | a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c
  4 | 602039
  5 | e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5
  5 | 176938
...
```

But that generates a query plan like this,

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append  (cost=0.00..33832.52 rows=1514052 width=64) (actual time=0.025..1034.740 rows=2000000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16916.26 rows=757026 width=64) (actual time=0.025..173.272 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..16916.26 rows=757026 width=64) (actual time=0.016..715.279 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.128 ms
 Execution time: 1103.499 ms
(5 rows)
```

What would it look like to have one sec scan, and would it be faster if the table was only read once?

[*Question inspired from this conversation*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35488343#35488343)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Answer inspired from this*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/157138/2639)

A few methods, all test with PostgreSQL 9.5.

### `CROSS JOIN LATERAL ... VALUES`

This is actually slower, but it seems good for a first attempt..

```
SELECT id, x
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES (md5),(trunc::text))
  AS t(x);

                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..50982.43 rows=1514052 width=64) (actual time=0.035..1934.061 rows=2000000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16916.26 rows=757026 width=72) (actual time=0.027..114.655 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=2 loops=1000000)
 Planning time: 0.115 ms
 Execution time: 2027.840 ms
(5 rows)
```

## `CROSS JOIN ... VALUES CASE`

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN x THEN md5 ELSE trunc::text END AS x 
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (true),(false))
  AS t(x);

                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..43412.20 rows=1514052 width=73) (actual time=0.036..1318.494 rows=2000000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16916.26 rows=757026 width=72) (actual time=0.026..108.375 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=2 width=1) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=2 loops=1000000)
         ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=1) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=2 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.104 ms
 Execution time: 1381.685 ms
(6 rows)
```

## Row duplication with `ARRAY/unnest`

```
SELECT id, x
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(ARRAY[md5,trunc::text])
  AS t(x);

                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..1530968.27 rows=75702600 width=64) (actual time=0.036..3329.324 rows=2000000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..16916.26 rows=757026 width=72) (actual time=0.015..156.087 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on unnest t  (cost=0.01..1.01 rows=100 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=2 loops=1000000)
 Planning time: 0.054 ms
 Execution time: 3439.064 ms
(5 rows)
```

## tldr;

Neither of these methods are faster. They're slower, and more complex. Stick with the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: That is unexpected. Because in SQL Server, the opposite is true. Using CROSS APPLY to double up the rows and do a single scan is about half the time of doing two scans.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is happening under the hood here, or why it has to be so or what optimizations are missing.

Comment: Maybe we should make another question as to why it's slower tag it with database-internals and wait for Erwin to answer it. Out of my pay grade past the work I've done here.

Comment: Technically, [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162688/need-to-export-table-into-2-columns-one-repeating-one-with-rest-stacked/162689) was the inspiration for the question.

Comment: I gave you the credit under the question for your post in the chat. =) Your inspiration for the chat is aside from my inspiration for the question. I already answered that question anyway. Every time I mention it a special someone wants to to have me banned for brining it up. So I leave it as-is.

Comment: Ah, I see now in the question. Was just confused.

Comment: What is faster or not *might* depend on whether the second scan finds everything already in memory, or a table sufficiently large (that will *not fit* in memory) ends up with minimal data cached. In the second case, the second scan will need to access disk a second time and be (possibly) more expensive than the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`. 1 M rows fits in memory of contemporary computers... but there is always a quantity that *doesn't fit*.

Comment: I found a simpler way which is `SELECT id, unnest(ARRAY[md5, trunc::text]) from foo;`. I did some testing and found that @joanolo is correct. If the entire table fits in shared buffers, the `UNION ALL` is faster. If it doesn't, the other solutions are faster as they only have to read from disk once.